# asp.net avoid navigation on enter key

Tags: asp.net, redirect

How can i avoid navigation when a user presses the  enter key on an asp.net page ?
Seems that they get redirected to the first page in the directory structure "Account\AccountRcovery"

I don't actually have any code to redirect to that page.
Also can this be disabled for the entire site ? as i have quite a few pages that would require modifications otherwise.

Edit: This seems to only affect IE ,doesn't happens in Firefox.

This is the content for an empty page, where this thing still hapens.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="test.aspx.cs" Inherits="Wip.test" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Are they pressing the enter key while focus is on a form element?  If that's not the behavior you're looking for then you'll probably have to capture the keypress in JavaScript and ignore it.

Comment: Nothing on the page has focus, this also happens with a blank page.

Comment: @lulian what browser do you use ?

Comment: @Aristos I've edited my question , this only happens in IE.

Comment: @lulian I think that you have editors on your page, and some of them get the focus. Need to give us some code for more help.

Comment: i've updated my question with a sample page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a button in the masterpage. When the user pressed enter on a apparently empty form that button was submitting the form and redirecting to AccountRecovery.